# Recent remote desktop connection sources

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop

How can I identify the source of recent remote desktop connections to my computer?

While at work I connected to my desktop there (XP SP3) from another system with files I want to access.  I am now at home and connected to my desktop at work but I do not know the name of the other system there.

Answer (score 1):

You can view connections made in the event log. You should see the hostname of the connection, you can then use that and work backwards.

Comment: any details?  which log?  what source, type, category?

Comment: Security Log, the task category is "Logon". For remote logons you will see "WORKSTATION NAME" in the details.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your settings the Event Viewer -> Security logs may have the information you need.

If you have a firewall and it logs connections, the information will be in there.